# if else statement inside forEach

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have array of ages, i want to know in what age range are those ages and how many, and then push into my object.

issue i have is that if there is more then 1 age in the same range it pushes twice, i want to push it once and display length of it, but it returns undefiened

here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-kkt7bc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
this.ages = [18, 20, 1];

this.ages.forEach((a) => {
  //infant
  if (a >= 0 && a <= 1) {
    this.id = 1;
    this.travel.listOfTravellerCountPerAgeRange.push({
      travellerAgeRangeId: this.id,
      travellerCount: a.length,
    });
  }

  //adult
  else if (a >= 12 && a <= 59) {
    this.id = 3;
    this.travel.listOfTravellerCountPerAgeRange.push({
      travellerAgeRangeId: this.id,
      travellerCount: a.length,
    });
  }
});
console.log(this.travel);
```

output i get from console.log is:

```
listOfTravellerCountPerAgeRange: [  
{travellerAgeRangeId: 3, travellerCount: undefined},
{travellerAgeRangeId: 3, travellerCount: undefined},  
{travellerAgeRangeId: 1, travellerCount: undefined} ]
```

output i wanna get:

```
 listOfTravellerCountPerAgeRange: [  
 {travellerAgeRangeId: 3, travellerCount: 2}, 
 {travellerAgeRangeId: 1, travellerCount: 1} ]
```

Comment: The reason it is `undefined` is because you are computing the length of the item of your array, which is a number and does not have a length property. In addition, why do you store travellers in a list? Would it not be simpler to have an `object` with a `travellerAgeRangeId` as key and `travellerCount` as value?

Comment: `a.length` is trying to evaluate the length of a number which is `undefined` for all numbers.

Comment: In this `forEach` loop, `a` is a number. You're trying to extract `length` from a number and that's why you're getting undefined. To create this logic you should check if the id already exists in the `listOfTravellerCountPerAgeRange` array and if it does, you add 1 to its respective `travellerCount` or something like that.

Comment: just a small comment: There's no logical reason to have this.id in your code. You have created a global variable that is never read except for the moment you are setting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count some value from the array items, you should use `reduce` method:

```js
this.travel = {};
this.ages = [1,1,45];

this.travel.listOfTravellerCountPerAgeRange = this.ages.reduce((acc, a) => {
  let id
  if (a >= 0 && a <= 1) {
    id = 1;
  } else if (a >= 12 && a <= 59) {
    id = 3;
  }
  const record = acc.find((entry) => entry.travellerAgeRangeId === id);
  if (record) {
     record.travellerCount += 1;
  } else {
    acc.push({travellerAgeRangeId: id, travellerCount: 1});
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(this.travel.listOfTravellerCountPerAgeRange);
```

I didn't run that code, but it should work =)

Comment: looks right to me. only question is: What behavior do you want  for age > 59?

Comment: @Rick `else { soylent green } `

Comment: @MetroSmurf not sure what "soylent green" means. I was directing my question to the OP who doesn't seem to account for scenarios with an age greater than 59.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer, i runed code but it returns acc.find is not a function :(

Comment: I've messed app the initial value. It should be [], not {}. Updated the answer with the working code snippet.